# How to select records based on the multiple conditions in snowflake-SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a snapshot of the below table where it shows only 1 line per user with same number of columns.

My Priority for selecting a user is from the source field by portal.

- Prod - 1
- QA - 2
- Stage - 3
- Max - 4

Below are the details --

- Each portal should have a unique line per member but selecting that line is based on the priority set for the source. (Prod, QA, Stage, Max)
- If there is no prod then will go with QA, and so on. But need only 1 line per user by portal. selection will be based on the priority of source as mentioned above.
- Please note that, userid '3543591' falls under AAA as well BBB portal. In this case, I would select 1 line from AAA where it has Prod and another line for BBB portal where it has Max because this userid does not have any data for Prod, QA, Max in portal BBB.

How do I achieve in Snowflake SQL? Please see the original table and expected output below.

ORIGINAL TABLE:

| Date | user | portal | country | state | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/1/21 | 2346232 | AAA | CA | ON | Prod |
| 1/30/22 | 2534657 | AAA | CA | BC | QA |
| 3/31/22 | 2534657 | AAA | US | TX | Max |
| 5/30/22 | 3454364 | AAA | US | TX | Prod |
| 7/29/22 | 3543591 | AAA | US | CA | Prod |
| 9/27/22 | 3543591 | AAA | US | CA | Max |
| 11/26/22 | 3543753 | AAA | US | CA | Stage |
| 1/25/23 | 3546534 | AAA | CA | ON | Max |
| 3/26/23 | 3543591 | BBB | US | CA | Max |

EXPECTED OUTPUT FROM SNOWFLAKE-SQL (highlighted in Bold):

| Date | user | portal | country | state | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **12/1/21** | **2346232** | **AAA** | **CA** | **ON** | **Prod** |
| **1/30/22** | **2534657** | **AAA** | **CA** | **BC** | **QA** |
| **5/30/22** | **3454364** | **AAA** | **US** | **TX** | **Prod** |
| **7/29/22** | **3543591** | **AAA** | **US** | **CA** | **Prod** |
| **11/26/22** | **3543753** | **AAA** | **US** | **CA** | **Stage** |
| **1/25/23** | **3546534** | **AAA** | **CA** | **ON** | **Max** |
| **3/26/23** | **3543591** | **BBB** | **US** | **CA** | **Max** |

Comment: can you provide a more concise example input/output data set.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim - I explained all the details in the question as well as the datasets. Can you please tell me what you are looking for? and I really appreciate your time on this. This is really important.

Comment: In general, you'll be more likely to obtain help on volunteer platforms if you make an attempt. Are you able to do some of this? How far can you get? You'll find that this will encourage people to help.

Comment: (And please note also that this is not urgent or important at all - everyone is a volunteer here!)

Comment: my feedback about this question (and not at you, just the question), is that your question spans three pages of my screen. To weave all that together is going to take a big lift from me. Skimming the statement, it seems unfocused, there appears to be edge case I will have to extract from the data, and it seems like half the data is not needed. If 20 rows are need to demonstrate the 7 different key requirements and each requires 3 rows to "action". Then sure 21 rows of data, but, break them up to show this data trigger this rule, this data trigger this rule.

Comment: I personally find when I go to this level of effort to frame my questions, and break it into small chunks, I ether start seeing solutions to parts of the problems, and can start see how to weave it all together... It also allows you to say, for this rule I tried this, and it worked, but then it break rule Y, and we can see what you know, and teach the gaps, or gain insights to the tricky parts of the data. Where as it stands it's a wall, now, I really value the data being in a table, verse a picture, so that is really good.

Comment: Hi @SimeonPilgrim, I have tried to remove unnecessary data and make it shorter. Apologize for this. I am still new to StackOverflow and learning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your data as a CTE:

```
with data(Date, user, portal, country, state, source) as (
    select * from values
    ('12/1/21 ', 2346232, 'AAA', 'CA', 'ON', 'Prod'),
    ('1/30/22 ', 2534657, 'AAA', 'CA', 'BC', 'QA'),
    ('3/31/22 ', 2534657, 'AAA', 'US', 'TX', 'Max'),
    ('5/30/22 ', 3454364, 'AAA', 'US', 'TX', 'Prod'),
    ('7/29/22 ', 3543591, 'AAA', 'US', 'CA', 'Prod'),
    ('9/27/22 ', 3543591, 'AAA', 'US', 'CA', 'Max'),
    ('11/26/22', 3543753, 'AAA', 'US', 'CA', 'Stage'),
    ('1/25/23 ', 3546534, 'AAA', 'CA', 'ON', 'Max'),
    ('3/26/23 ', 3543591, 'BBB', 'US', 'CA', 'Max')
)
```

and a simple check of the rules:

using a CASE statement to turn `source` into a number for ordering, and using [row_number()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) to allocate a per protal/user ranking:

```
select d.*
    ,case source
        when 'Prod' then 1
        when 'QA' then 2
        when 'Stage' then 3
        when 'Max' then 4
    end as rank
    ,row_number() over (partition by portal, user order by rank) as rn
from data as d;
```

gives:

| DATE | USER | PORTAL | COUNTRY | STATE | SOURCE | RANK | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/1/21 | 2,346,232 | AAA | CA | ON | Prod | 1 | 1 |
| 1/30/22 | 2,534,657 | AAA | CA | BC | QA | 2 | 1 |
| 3/31/22 | 2,534,657 | AAA | US | TX | Max | 4 | 2 |
| 5/30/22 | 3,454,364 | AAA | US | TX | Prod | 1 | 1 |
| 7/29/22 | 3,543,591 | AAA | US | CA | Prod | 1 | 1 |
| 9/27/22 | 3,543,591 | AAA | US | CA | Max | 4 | 2 |
| 11/26/22 | 3,543,753 | AAA | US | CA | Stage | 3 | 1 |
| 1/25/23 | 3,546,534 | AAA | CA | ON | Max | 4 | 1 |
| 3/26/23 | 3,543,591 | BBB | US | CA | Max | 4 | 1 |

at this point it looks good, now we can use a [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) to only take the values we want, but first we can swap the CASE for a [DECODE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/decode.html) to make it more tidy to use in-line:

thus:

```
,DECODE(source, 'Prod', 1, 'QA', 2, 'Stage', 3, 'Max', 4)
```

gives the same results as the case, thus the solution is:

```
select d.*
from data as d
qualify row_number() over (partition by portal, user order by DECODE(source, 'Prod', 1, 'QA', 2, 'Stage', 3, 'Max', 4)) = 1
```

| DATE | USER | PORTAL | COUNTRY | STATE | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/1/21 | 2,346,232 | AAA | CA | ON | Prod |
| 1/30/22 | 2,534,657 | AAA | CA | BC | QA |
| 5/30/22 | 3,454,364 | AAA | US | TX | Prod |
| 7/29/22 | 3,543,591 | AAA | US | CA | Prod |
| 11/26/22 | 3,543,753 | AAA | US | CA | Stage |
| 1/25/23 | 3,546,534 | AAA | CA | ON | Max |
| 3/26/23 | 3,543,591 | BBB | US | CA | Max |

a side note:

you data did not need `date`, `country`, or `state`,
and user `3454364` repeated the same logic of `2346232`

so could have just been, and likely could have been smaller again.

```
with data(user, portal, source) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 'A', 'Prod'),
    (2, 'A', 'QA'),
    (2, 'A', 'Max'),
    (4, 'A', 'Prod'),
    (4, 'A', 'Max'),
    (5, 'A', 'Stage'),
    (6, 'A', 'Max'),
    (4, 'B', 'Max')
)
select d.*
from data as d
qualify row_number() over (partition by portal, user order by DECODE(source, 'Prod', 1, 'QA', 2, 'Stage', 3, 'Max', 4)) = 1
```

| USER | PORTAL | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Prod |
| 2 | A | QA |
| 4 | A | Prod |
| 5 | A | Stage |
| 6 | A | Max |
| 4 | B | Max |

Comment: Thank you @SimeonPilgrim. I will work on the real data with the same example. I hope this doesn't cost much. 
P.s. I learned something new about DECODE.